# How to store emoji string in Database using Laravel with Orm Query

Tags: laravel, orm, emoji

I want to store special character in database vice versa like emotive but when I try to save in database I get question marks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your `database.php` file, make sure to set the `charset` and `collation` to `utf8mb4`:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

And your emoji column should be a String:

`$table->string('emoji');`

Comment: where is the `database.php` located in laravel 5?

Comment: @Webinan in the `config` folder

Comment: oh, I'm using Lumen and I don't have such folder named `config`.

Comment: @Webinan in that case, per the Lumen  docs: `you may use the DB_* configuration options in your .env configuration file to configure your database settings, such as the driver, host, username, and password.`

Comment: **THANK YOU!** `DB_CHARSET` + `DB_COLLECTION` did the job. :*

Comment: 2 years 4 months has passed and this still can save my day, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Ensure you're using MYSQL 5.5.3 or later then will you be able to change the collation to utf8mb4_something,

2) Ensure table columns that are going to receive emoji have their collation set to utf8mb4_something

if still you have issue, then Edit your database.php config file and update following,

```
    'charset' = 'utf8mb4';
'collation' = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers above, make sure to clear cache and migrate refresh to update the MySQL tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using websocket for chat and sending Emoticons, then you have to restart the websocket.

You can find and kill all the websocket processes like
`sudo kill (Your PID)` without the round brackets.

And for the ? Marks, it's okay because some browsers, or MySQL editors not supporting Emoticons, so they show you questions (?) marks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and easiest way is to change your charset to utf8mb4

`charset => utf8mb4`