# Flask SQLAlchemy can't insert emoji to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm using **Python 2.7** and flask framework with **flask-sqlalchemy** module.

I always get the following exception when trying to insert : `Exception Type: OperationalError. Exception Value: (1366, "Incorrect string value: \xF09...`

I already set MySQL database, table and corresponding column to `utf8mb4_general_ci` and I can insert emoji string using terminal.

Flask's app config already contains `app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'`, however it doesn't help at all and I still get the exception.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
 import pickle 
 data = request.get_json().get("data") 
 data = pickle.dumps(data)
```

Then you can input the "data" to the database .

You can send the "data" like "" ...Whatever emoji you like.

Next time, when you get the "data" from the database :

you should :

```
data = pickle.loads(data)
```

then you can get "data" as ""

Answer (score 7):

maybe this will someone in the future:
all i did was edit the sql connection in my config file:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/database?charset=utf8mb4'
```

this way i'm able to store emojis without any altering of the database or tables.

source: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database/page/13%0A Comment #322

Answer (score 0):

1. Add config file main file and set set `'charset' => 'utf8mb4'`
2. you have to edit field in which you want to store emoji and set `collation` as `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: Thanks for answer! I already set collation, forgot to mention it, sorry. Can you specify what you mean by "config file main file"

Comment: i mean in you config file means where you define your database for project and all other stuff

Comment: Sir, There's no 'charset' field in 'app.config' dictionary, only field that could relate is called 'mysql_database_charset' and I have already changed it.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636783/how-to-store-emoji-string-in-database-using-laravel-with-orm-query may be this could help

Comment: I already can add rows using my terminal, so it's not mysql problem. I think it should be strongly related to flask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use a proper Python Unicode object, like the ones created with the `u"..."` literal. In other words, the type of your object should be `unicode` not `str`:

```
>>> type('ą')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(u'ą')
<type 'unicode'>
```

Please note that this only applies to Python 2, in Python 3 all string literals are Unicode by default.